# SSL Provider: La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía. Django y SQL

Tags: python, sql, django

Tengo un problema con una conexión, soy bastante nuevo en esto pero necesito hacer un trabajo de conexión en django, ahorita estoy usando un entorno virtual de python para conectarme a SQL server pero a la hora de hacer "makemigrations" me sale el error de

"SSL Provider: La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía"

Este es mi código que intentando arreglar he metido muchas "options" incluso innecesarias

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'Pagina_AND',  # Nombre base de datos
    'HOST': r'LENOVOIDEAPAD\SQLEXPRESS',  # Nombre del servidor SQL Server
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
        'encrypt': False,  # Habilita la conexión SSL
        'Trusted_Connection': 'yes',  # Autenticación de Windows
        'TrustServerCertificate': False,
    },
    
}
```

}

Y mi configuración de SQL tiene "Encrypt connection" y "Trust server certificate" sin estar activados, está default la configuración